# I need to force ssl on main domain but not subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

The main site at www.mydomain.com is set up as a secure site using an SSL certificate.

I need to create a subdomain that is not secured (http://open.mydomain.com).

I'm hosting with InMotionHosting.com. I've created the subdomain in cPanel and pointed it to the folder at public_html/open (the main site is at public_html/mainsite) but when I try to visit the subdomain URL I get an SSL error in Chrome, and in IE I get redirected to https://www.mydomain.com/open.

How do I fix this?

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, this no longer forces the main domain to SSL so it's possible to use the main site non-securely. Perhaps I wasn't clear on that, but I need www.mydomain.com to be secure ALWAYS and open.mydomain.com to be secure NEVER>

Comment: Are you behind some proxy by any chance, otherwise 1st rule enforces `www.mydomain.com` to be always https. Do you have other rules also?

Comment: No, not behind a proxy and the code you gave me is all that is in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to modify this slightly. When I enter `www.mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com` in the browser, it is forced to https. But when I enter `http://www.mydomain.com` it is not -- it stays in unsecured mode and I can navigate through the site unsecured.

Comment: It is confusing. You wrote `www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com in the browser, it is forced to https` then wrote opposite that `http://www.mydomain.com` is not. Aren't `www.mydomain.com` and `http://www.mydomain.com` same?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

If you want several subdomains change the line like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(sub|lolo).example.com$
```